# css file not working properly on rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

css is not working properly in rails 4.2.5 on implementing home page looks like

the gem file are

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

my routes are

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/resources'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  resources :categories
  get 'categories/index'

  get 'categories/edit'

  get 'categories/new'

  get 'categories/show'

  get 'home/index'

  resources :posts
  root 'home#index'
end
```

my css files are:

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #000000;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #6F6F6F;
}
strong {
 color: #3F3F3F;
}
h1,h2,h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #2B2522;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 2.8em;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 1.6em;
}
p,ul,ol {
 margin-top: 0;
 line-height: 180%;
}
ul,ol {

}
a {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #D93544;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 background: #000000; 
}

/* Header */
#header-wrapper {
 height: 120px;
}
#header {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/* Logo */
#logo {
 float: left;
 width: 350px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000000;
}
#logo h1, #logo p {

}

#logo h1 {
 margin-left: 30px;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
 font-size: 3.8em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #D43442;
}

#logo h1 a {
 color: #D43442;
}

#logo h1 span {

}

#logo p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px 0 0 32px;
 font: normal 14px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #BEBEBE;
}

#logo a {
 border: none;
 background: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #707070
}


/* Search */
#search {
 float: right;
 width: 280px;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px
}


#search form {
 height: 41px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
}

#search fieldset {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}

#search-text {
 width: 170px;
 height: 19px;
 padding: 4px 5px 1px 5px;
 border: none;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #5D781D;
}

#search-submit {
 width: 50px;
 height: 26px;
 background: #D93544;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Menu */
#menu {
 float: right;
 height: 125px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 background: #D43442;
}

#menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
 float: left;
 border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu a {
 display: block;
 height: 80px;
 padding: 45px 25px 0px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a{
 background: #A32833;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {

}

/* Page */

#page {
 width: 980px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#page-bgtop {
 padding: 20px 0px;
}

/* Content */

#content {
 float: right;
 width: 600px;
 padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.post, .post_full, .page {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px;
 background: #FFFFFF url (images/page-gradient-bg.png) repeat-x left bottom;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
 outline: 1px dashed #D4D4D4;
 outline-offset: -5px;

}

.post .title, .page .title {
 height: 41px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

.post .title a, .page .title a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #202020;
 border: none;
}

.post .entry {
 padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
}

.post .byline {
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.post .meta {
 float: left;
}

.post .links {
 float: right;
}

/* Full Post */
.post_full .byline p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.post_full .byline {
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 5px;
 background: black:;
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 5px #D93544 solid;
}

.links a {

}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#sidebar ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li ul {
 margin: 0px 0px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#sidebar li li {
 line-height: 35px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #191919;
 background: url (images/img01.jpg) no-repeat left 15px;
 margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
 border-left: none;
 text-align: left;
}

#sidebar li li span {
 display: block;
 margin-top: -20px;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-style: italic;
}

#sidebar li li a {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#sidebar h2 {
 height: 31px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
 background: url(images/img03.jpg) no-repeat left top;
 text-shadow: #203060 -1px 1px 2px;
 text-align: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: -0.5em;
 font-size: 2em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sidebar p {
 margin: 0 0px;
 padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 color: #847F7E;
}

#sidebar a {
 border: none;
 color: #847F7E;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #847F7E;
}

/* Calendar */
#calender { 
}

#calender_wrap{
 padding:20px;
}
#calender table {
 width: 100%;
}
#calendar body td {
 text-align: center;
}
#calendar #next {
 text-align: right;
}
/footer/
#footer{
 width: 980px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 0 15px 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#footer p {
 margin: 0;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 color: #847F7E;
}

#footer a {
 color: 847F7E;
}

form label{width: 110px; display: inline-block;}
```

looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uktw.png)

want home about contact to be in column form
and want to remove the header background

Comment: sidenote: Your routes.rb seems to ordered wrong: the convention is to define `root` at the very top, then define `resources` and then `get/put/patch` or whatever else you have.

Comment: Didn' help the format is still the same

Comment: please provide HTML

Comment: its ok got it thank you